# Telegram bot with python, prints "Channel post is None" message but channel

Tags: python, python-telegram-bot

The Telegram bot is coded with Python, the problem is that it cannot save the information of the last channel post in the database, and while the channel is not empty of posts, it prints the message "Channel post is None" Python 3.11.5 I  , python-telegram-bot version 20.6:

```
from typing import Final
from telegram import Update
from telegram.ext import Application, CommandHandler, MessageHandler, filters, ContextTypes
import sqlite3
import telegram
TOKEN: Final = "66jbhkjdsakfasdfZR4zRyOmWUFXn8p1clR6iPVmD"
BOT_USERNAME = "@jbt_content_bot"

# Database connection
conn = sqlite3.connect('database.db')
c = conn.cursor()

# Create table if it doesn't exist
c.execute('''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS posts (
    channel_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    post_id INTEGER,
    text TEXT,
    photo TEXT,
    mentions TEXT
)''')
# Command
async def start_command(update: Update , context : ContextTypes.DEFAULT_TYPE):
    await update.message.reply_text("ok")


async def help_command(update: Update , context : ContextTypes.DEFAULT_TYPE):
    await update.message.reply_text("im helper ")

async def getlastPostChannel_command (update: Update , context : ContextTypes.DEFAULT_TYPE):
    if update.channel_post is not None:
        # Get the channel ID from the update
        channel_id = update.channel_post.chat.id
        # Get the bot's ID
        bot_id = context.bot.id
        # Check if the bot is a member of the channel and has read access
        try:
            chat_member = context.bot.get_chat_member(channel_id, bot_id)
            if chat_member.status not in ["creator", "administrator", "member", "restricted"]:
                raise telegram.error.Unauthorized("The bot is not a member of the channel or has no read access.")
        except telegram.error.Unauthorized as e:
            # The bot was kicked from the channel or has no read access
            print(f"Error: {e.message}")
            return

        # Get the last post of the channel
        last_post = await context.bot.get_message(channel_id, -1)

        # Save the post information to the database
        c.execute('''INSERT INTO posts (channel_id, post_id, text, photo, mentions) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)''',
                    (channel_id, last_post.message_id, last_post.text, last_post.photo.file_id,
                     last_post.caption_entities))
        conn.commit()

        # Send a confirmation message to the user
        await update.message.reply_text('The last post of the channel has been saved to the database.')
    else:
        print("Channel post is None")

async def custom_command(update: Update , context : ContextTypes.DEFAULT_TYPE):
    await update.message.reply_text("custome")


# Handel responses

def handel_response(text: str) -> str:
    processed:str = text.lower()
    if "hello" in processed:
        return "hiiiiii"

    elif "how are you" in processed:
        return "i`m good"

    elif "hello" in processed:
        return "hiiiiii"
    else:
        return "sikitir"


async def handel_message(update: Update , context : ContextTypes.DEFAULT_TYPE):
    if update.message is not None:
        message_type: str = update.message.chat.type
        text: str = update.message.text

        print(f'User({update.message.id}) in {message_type}:{text}')

        if message_type == 'group':

            if BOT_USERNAME in text:
                new_text: str = text.replace(BOT_USERNAME, '').strip()
                response: str = handel_response(new_text)

            else:
                return
        else:
            response: str = handel_response(text)

        print('Bot :', response)
        await update.message.reply_text(response)
    else:
        print("Message is None")

async def error(update: Update, context: ContextTypes.DEFAULT_TYPE):
    print(f'Update{update},caused error{context.error}')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print('Starting Bot')
    app = Application.builder().token(TOKEN).build()

    app.add_handler(CommandHandler('start', start_command))
    app.add_handler(CommandHandler('help', help_command))
    app.add_handler(CommandHandler('custom', custom_command))
    app.add_handler(CommandHandler('post', getlastPostChannel_command))

    # message
    app.add_handler(MessageHandler(filters.TEXT, handel_message))

    # Errors

    app.add_error_handler(error)
    # Polls
    print('polling ...')

    app.run_polling(poll_interval=2)
```

I am using Telegram Bot API 21.4 and Python 3.11.5 I  , python-telegram-bot version 20.6 ,Iam trying to save the information of the last channel post in the database, but I am getting the message "Channel post is None".

I have checked the following:

The bot is a member of the channel and has read access.
The channel is not empty of posts.
I am not sure why the bot is unable to save the information of the last channel post in the database. I would appreciate any help that you can provide.

Answer (score 0):

In your function `getlastPostChannel_command`, the argument `update` is the message that contains the command `/post`. It is *not* the last post in your channel.

Telegram sends updates to bots as they come in and PTBs handler setup is designed to handle them one by one. Please be sure to read [PTBs tutorial](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/wiki/Extensions---Your-first-Bot). In particular, there is no such thing as `Bot.get_message` (see also [here](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#can-you-add-feature-to-ptb-can-i-do-thing-with-my-bot))

So you will need a handler that handles channel posts. You already have a `MessageHandler(filters.TEXT, handel_message)` in place which does that. You'll just need to check if `update.channel_post is not None`. Note that you can also use [`filters.UpdateType.CHANNEL_POST`](https://docs.python-telegram-bot.org/en/stable/telegram.ext.filters.html#telegram.ext.filters.UpdateType.CHANNEL_POST) for that.

---

Disclaimer: I'm currently the maintainer of `python-telegram-bot`.